# Update in one Concurrentdictionary is reflected in main dictionary

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have two concurrent dictionaries say

```
 var MainDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
```

and

```
var TempDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(MainDic);
```

My `TempDic` contains same data as `MainDic`.I do computations on `TempDic`. whatever changes are made to `TempDic` is reflected in `MainDic`. How do i stop this ,i need to keep `MainDic` as it is for further reference

Following is my actual code:

ConcurrentDictionary NetPositionData = new ConcurrentDictionary(); // Main Dic

```
    private DataView GetNetPositionData()
    {
        this.NetPosition.Tables[0].Rows.Clear();
        DataView view = new DataView();
        ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataNetPosition> Postion;
        if (NetPosFlag == "A")
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataNetPosition> entry in NetPositionData)
            {
                this.NetPosition.Tables[0].Rows.Add(entry.Value.Exchange, entry.Value.SecurityId, entry.Value.ClientId, entry.Value.LTP);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Postion = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataNetPosition>(GetDayPosition(NetPositionData));
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DataNetPosition> entry in Postion)
            {
                this.NetPosition.Tables[0].Rows.Add(entry.Value.Exchange, entry.Value.SecurityId, entry.Value.ClientId, entry.Value.LTP);
            }
        }
        return view;
    }

    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataNetPosition> GetDayPosition(ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataNetPosition> _ALLPos)
    {
        var _DayPos = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataNetPosition>(_ALLPos);
        try
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(CFnetposition.Tables[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string NKey = dv.Table.Rows[i]["Exchange"].ToString() + dv.Table.Rows[i]["SecurityId"].ToString() + dv.Table.Rows[i]["ClientID"].ToString() + dv.Table.Rows[i]["Product"].ToString();
                if (_DayPos.ContainsKey(NKey))
                {
                    var dnp = _DayPos[NKey];
                    if (dv.Table.Rows[i]["Buy/Sell"].ToString() == "Buy")
                    {
                        dnp.BuyQuantity = dnp.BuyQuantity - Convert.ToDouble(dv.Table.Rows[i]["Quantity"]);
                        dnp.BuyVal = dnp.BuyVal - Convert.ToDouble(dv.Table.Rows[i]["TradeValue"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dnp.SellQuantity = dnp.SellQuantity - Convert.ToDouble(dv.Table.Rows[i]["Quantity"]);
                        dnp.SellVal = dnp.SellVal - Convert.ToDouble(dv.Table.Rows[i]["TradeValue"]);
                    }

                    dnp.BuyAvg = dnp.BuyQuantity == 0 ? 0 : dnp.BuyVal / dnp.BuyQuantity;
                    dnp.SellAvg = dnp.SellQuantity == 0 ? 0 : dnp.SellVal / dnp.SellQuantity;
                    dnp.NetQuantity = dnp.BuyQuantity - dnp.SellQuantity;
                    // other caluculations 
                    _DayPos.TryUpdate(NKey, dnp, null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return _DayPos;
    }
```

here if flag is A i return data as it is else i call GetDayPosition. In GetDayPosition function whatever update i make in _DayPos is reflected in NetPositionData dictionary as well. because of this i lose my original data. I don't want this to happen

Comment: What do you mean by "computation"? Please could you include an example, a small script that shows what you do and what you want to outputed.

Comment: I have added my code ,please refer and let me know what mistake i am doing.

Comment: You need to learn about the difference between `deep-copy` vs `shallow-copy`. `var TempDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(MainDic)` is what we call a `shallow-copy`, you need to do a `deep-copy` for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Aron Deep-copy solved my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that?

```
        var mainDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        mainDic["1"] = "foo";

        var tempDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>(mainDic);
        tempDic["1"] = "bar";

        Console.Out.WriteLine(mainDic["1"]);
```

outputs -> foo

Comment: I suspect that the OP over simplified their example. I suspect that the type in question is a mutable reference type, and the problem lies not in the Dictionary, but the both Dictionaries holding references to the same objects.